# Outlook add-in saveAsync creates an appointment

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have created an Office add-in using OfficeJs which works as follow,

1. At the time of creating/updating an appointment (Outlook or OWA) user uses Outlook add-in and the add-in sets some custom property using *set(name, value)* method.
2. As per documentation we trigger *saveAsync(callback, asyncContext)* which automatically saves the appointment/event on exchange.
3. Secondly, we have subscribed for Microsoft Graph API notifications to get an update as soon as there is an event change in someone's calendar.

**Problem:** 
 - The problem that we have here is that, as soon as user perform step 1 above. The system triggers *saveAsync(callback, asyncContext)* automatically resulting an event being created in user's calendar.
 - Also caused a notification being triggered by O365 to us as we had subscribed to them.
 - We analyzed it and found that the OfficeJS API sets a property named **IsDraft** for its internal use.
 - But unfortunately, when I extract same event using Graph API the property is not available. We also analyzed Graph API subscriptions for a provision to skip such notifications but again, supported subscription types are create/update/delete only.

This is really a blocker for us. We can try for a work around but first want to check if there is any formal way of handling it like **any property that can explicitly be asked during graph api get call which can help us identifying such events**.

Answer (score 0):

As updating the custom property is also a change in the event you will receive the notification and currently no such filter or property exist to differentiate these two types of the changes. You will have to handle this in your code.

Comment: Thanks team. We are trying different options but can we expect any formal solution in near future because handling it locally is not that reliable?

Comment: Currently this requirement is not there in our backlog, we suggest you to build filtering mechanism on your end to handle this requirement.

Comment: Thanks team. we had figured out a filtering mechanism at over end.